# Appending a new line to file

Tags: python, file-io

I am wondering how to append a newline every time the list reaches the size of the checker board (8). Heres my code so far. It works but I want to put a newline every 8 characters.

```
 saveFile=input("Please enter the name of the file you want to save in: ")
  outputFile=open(saveFile,"w")
  pieceList=[]
  for row_index in range (self.SIZE):
     for column_index in range(self.SIZE):
        pieceRow=[]
        char=" "
        if self.grid[row_index][column_index]==Piece(Piece.WHITE):
           char="w"
        elif self.grid[row_index][column_index]==Piece(Piece.RED):
           char="r"
        pieceRow.append(char)
     pieceList.append(pieceRow)
     for item in pieceList:
        for char in item:
           outputFile.write("%s" %char)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
saveFile=input("Please enter the name of the file you want to save in: ")
  outputFile=open(saveFile,"w")
  pieceList=[]
  characterCounter =0
  for row_index in range (self.SIZE):
     for column_index in range(self.SIZE):
        pieceRow=[]
        char=" "
        if self.grid[row_index][column_index]==Piece(Piece.WHITE):
           char="w"
        elif self.grid[row_index][column_index]==Piece(Piece.RED):
           char="r"
        pieceRow.append(char)
        characterCounter++
        if characterCounter==8:
           pieceRow.append("\n")
           characterCounter=0
     pieceList.append(pieceRow)
     for item in pieceList:
        for char in item:
           outputFile.write("%s" %char)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if row_index % 8 == 0:
    # put newline
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt = 0 
for item in pieceList:
    for char in item:
       outputFile.write("%s" %char)
       cnt += 1
       if cnt == 8:
           outputFile.write("\n")
           cnt = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to append newline after each row?
Why not add

```
pieceRow.append("\n")
```

before

```
pieceList.append(pieceRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use enumerate,

For instance,
    CONST_SIZE = 8

```
for index, item in enumerate(item_list):
    output_file.write(item)
    if index % 8 == 0: output_file.write('\n')
```

This will append a newline each time you've written 8 items to the file.